# CKEDITOR Can't see content area with DecoupledEditor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

I'm using CKEDITOR5 with React and I have succeed to implement CKEDITOR in my project but when I go on my view I can only see the toolbar.

The content area is invisible until I click on it and the blue border appear.

If I remove my focus on it there is no border anymore.

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import DecoupledEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document';


export default class BlogNew extends Component {
render() {
return (
<div>
  <CKEditor
   editor={ DecoupledEditor }
   onInit={ editor => {
            editor.ui.getEditableElement().parentElement.insertBefore(
            editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
            editor.ui.getEditableElement()
            );
           } }
   onChange={(event, editor) => {
             const data = editor.getData();
             this.setState({ text: data })
             }}
     />
</div>
)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DecoupledEditor is dedicated to integrations which require a customized UI.
Make sure to add the style to your component:

```
:root {
  .ck.ck-editor__editable_inline {
    border: 1px solid var(--ck-color-base-border);
  }
}
```

see @ [ckeditor5-ui](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark/blob/0fe15002767d4e1a9fe35981a1a1fdcee6458cd2/theme/ckeditor5-ui/components/editorui/editorui.css#L24)